# How to remove 1st numeric value?

Tags: javascript

Please help me to remove 1st numeric value. This is my code:

```html
<body>

<input type='text' name="fbvurl" value='aaaaaaa12345zzzzzzzzz67856' />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = document['getElementsByName']('fbvurl')[0]['value']; 
    var res = str.match(/\d+/g)
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The answer I get is

```
12345,67856
```

but I want only 67856.
Any other way to get last numeric value from string?

Comment: `str.match(/\d+$/)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the last match using `res[res.length-1]`.

```html
<input type='text' name="fbvurl" value='aaaaaaa12345zzzzzzzzz67856' />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var str = document['getElementsByName']('fbvurl')[0]['value'];
    var res = str.match(/\d+/g)
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[res.length-1];
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works regardless of whether numerals are the last characters in your string. It works by getting all numerical blocks and then getting the last from the array.

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = document['getElementsByName']('fbvurl')[0]['value'];

    // returns an array of all numbers in the string
    var allNumbers = str.match(/\d+/g); 

    // gets the last element in the array
    var lastNumber = allNumbers[allNumbers.length-1]

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = lastNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.match()` returns an array of results. Currently your code prints the entire array, which means the program is forced to put commas between the results. Try extending your JS function so it takes the last elements of `res` using `res[res.length - 1]`.

```html
<body>
<input type='text' name="fbvurl" value='aaaaaaa12345zzzzzzzzz67856' />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try taking last array element</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = document['getElementsByName']('fbvurl')[0]['value']; 
    var res = str.match(/\d+/g);
    var reslast = res[res.length - 1];
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = reslast;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Still having a problem please make it fix please

```html
<html>
<body>

<script>
function allf () {
 myFunction();
 ifgenerator ();
}
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementsByName('fbvurl')[0]['value']; 
    var res = str.match(/\d+/g) 
 document.getElementById("fbvid").innerHTML = res[1]
}
function ifgenerator() {
   var vidid = document.getElementById('fbvid').textContent;
   var ifcode = document['getElementsByName']('content')[0];
   ifcode['value'] = '<iframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=' + vidid + '\" width=\"550\" height=\"400\" frameborder=\"0\"> </iframe>';
}
</script>
<input type='text' name="fbvurl" value='https://www.facebook.com/12321444/videos/864302276997647/' />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="fbvid"></p>
<input value='Generate' style='font-size:16px;width:115px;line-height:25px;font-weight:bold;' type='button' onclick='javascript:ifgenerator();' />

<textarea name="content" onfocus="this.select()" onmouseover="this.focus()" onclick="this.focus();this.select()" style=background:#ffffff;width:100%;height:100px;' readonly='readonly' ></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should be a new question, and it may get automatically deleted, but I edited your `ifgenerator()`. Kindly ask new questions in the future to keep questions isolated to a single issue. :)

Comment: Ok sir. i m newbie here